# css grid - how do I put equal space between columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Trying to setup a css grid layout for my app navigation bar, but I am having trouble getting the justify-content property to work. Here I am trying to set it to center, but what I really want is a layout where the gutter space expands according to the space available.

Fiddle of the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/epch33vx/

My html:

```
<div class='test'>
  <div class='item'>
    1
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    2
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    3
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

My stylesheet:

```
.test {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(56px, 80px));
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  justify-items: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 56px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an image of the desired outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `justify-items: center;` with `justify-content: space-between;`

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#row-align) (bold mine):

> Note that certain values of justify-content and align-content can
>   cause the tracks to be spaced apart (space-around, **space-between**,
>   space-evenly)

```css
.test {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(56px, 80px));
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 56px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <div class='item'>
    1
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    2
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    3
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

### [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/epch33vx/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that `display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;` should go into test class.

Comment: Want to get the same result using css grid, but in theory your solution works